# How to conditionally add rows to a spreadsheet based on cell values in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to do the following using Excel:

Below is a table of booleans and unique identifiers.

This is what I would like to achieve. If the first column says "No", I would like the code to automatically add a whole new row in a separate spreadsheet with the unique identifier in the first column of the new row (shown below is spreadsheet 1).

[image: Spreadsheet 1]

In this case C4 and C5 would be the two rows exemplified below (spreadsheet 2).

[image: Result]

Code updated:

```
Sub AddID()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Questionnaire")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AI Tracker")

    j = 1
    For Each c In Source.Range("C4:C54")
        If c = "No" Then
           Target.Cells(j + 4, "A").Value = c.Offset(, 1).Value
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

This updates the target worksheet correctly but I need it to do update if the Source worksheet is altered (i.e. if something is changed to No, the function should add the new row to the Target sheet).

I have made the following code to detect changes but it does not work:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("C4:C54")) _
       Is Nothing Then
        Call Module2.AddID
        MsgBox "Cell has changed"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What did you try? please post your code

Comment: I have added a code snippet @litelite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things were greatly simplified and I have come up with the following solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim n
    Dim a

    Set dest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AI Tracker")

    If Intersect(Target, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("C4:C54")) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    Else

        a = Target.Address
        n = Range(a).Offset(, 1).Value

            If Target.Value = "No" Then
                dest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = n
            End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This will detect a "No" and then find the next empty row in the destination worksheet and add the Unique Identifier (associated with the "No") to the first cell in that row.

Comment: see my edited answer for your _**current**_ needs. and consider my comment for your _**original**_ ones.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
```

use

```
Target.Cells(j,"A").Value = c.Offset(,1).value '<~~ change "A" column index to whatever you need to be copied Unique identifier into
```

**edited**

following your further needs and the solution you posted 1 hour ago, consider the following optimization

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Intersect(Target, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Questionnaire").Range("C4:C54")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub '<~~ use just one row and avoid the "Else-End If" block. it increases readability

    Dim dest As Worksheet '<~~ Dim only if needed, i.e. if you didn't exit the sub
    Set dest = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AI Tracker") '<~~ Set only if needed,i.e. if you didn't exit the sub
    If Target.Value = "No" Then dest.Range("A" & dest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Target.Offset(, 1).Value '<~~ Target has already all you need and it's already a range

End Sub
```

still it remains to deal with some conditions. for instance: what if `Target` is a multiple cells `Range`?

Comment: I have made the changes but the code does not automatically detect changes and therefore add them to the Target worksheet. It only updates when I run the code. It works but needs to be active during changes,

Comment: If my answer fulfilled your _**original**_ question, then please mark it as accepted. thank you.

Comment: If I wanted to check for "No" then copy not only one cell but the adjacent cell to the destination worksheet, how would I edit this code?

Comment: Use Resize(rows,columns) method of the Range Object that allows you to extend the range it's called upon both horizontally and vertically to needed size. So, to extend myRange range horizontally by one cell (column) you'd use myRange.Offset(,2) i.e asking for no rows-two columns resizing.  dest.Range("A" & dest.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(,2).Value = Target.Offset(, 1).Resize(,2).Value